# Get all ids of multiselect box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this code I can move the options from left to right and from right to left. Now I need to get all the ids from the left box. How do i do that?

JS:

```
$("#moveright").click(function(){
       $("#country > option:selected").each(function(){
          $(this).remove().appendTo("#planets");
        });
    });

$("#moveleft").click(function(){
     $("#planets > option:selected").each(function(){
       $(this).remove().appendTo("#country");
     });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cover">
      <select id="country" multiple="multiple" name="country" >
       <option id="a">Afghanistan</option>
       <option id="b">Albania</option>
       <option id="c">Algeria</option>
       <option id="d">Andorra</option>
       </select>
   <input id="moveright" type="button" value="  >  " />
   <input id="moveleft" type="button" value="  <  " />
    <select id="planets" multiple="multiple" name="planets">
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a5dyrvpx/1/

Comment: ids of going out? coming in? just ids of initial items?

Comment: @Alves didn't my answer solve your problem, you accepted it and then canceled the acceptation..

Answer (score 0):

By introducing a button with a click event it could look like this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="mybtn">get all id's (see console)</button>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('mybtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const options = document.getElementById('country').options;
      for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        console.log(options[i].id)
      }
    })
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omw9uqer/

Answer (score 0):

> I think this what you are asking about !

```js
 $("#moveright").click(function(){
    x = '';
   $("#country > option:selected").each(function(){
        $(this).remove().appendTo("#planets");
   });
});

 $("#moveleft").click(function(){
   x = '';
   $("#planets > option:selected").each(function(){
        $(this).remove().appendTo("#country");
   });
});

var x = '';
function myFunction(){
  for(i = 0; i < $('#country option').length; i++){
    x += $('#country option:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id') + ' ';
  }
  alert(x)
}
```

```css
<style>
    * {
      margin:       0px;
      padding:      0px;
    }

    html, body {
      font-size:    12px;
      font-family:  sans-serif;
      background:   #f5f5f5;
    }

    .cover {
      padding:      20px 30px;
      border:       1px solid #dedede;
      border-radius:4px;
      background:   #f9f9f9;
      box-shadow:   0px 0px 10px #a8a8a8;

      /* centering */
      position:     absolute;
      top:          50%;
      left:         50%;
      /*margin-top:  -180px;*/
      margin-left: -222px;
    }

    .lbjs { float: left; }
    .lbjs:last-of-type { margin-left: 20px; }
    
    button {
      clear: both
    }
  </style>
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="cover">
    <select id="country" multiple="multiple" name="country" >
      <option id="a">Afghanistan</option>
      <option id="b">Albania</option>
      <option id="c">Algeria</option>
      <option id="d">Andorra</option>
    </select>
<input id="moveright" type="button" value="  >  " />
<input id="moveleft" type="button" value="  <  " />
    <select id="planets" multiple="multiple" name="planets">
     
    </select>
  </div><!-- .cover -->
  <button onclick='myFunction()'>Show IDs</button>
```